# Given $\boldsymbol{x} = \boldsymbol{y } \boldsymbol{A}$ with $ | \boldsymbol{x}|_{\infty} \le c $ , find a bound on $|\boldsymbol{y} | _{\infty}$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, inequality, normed-spaces, matrix-equations

**Problem**

Given
\begin{equation}\label{4}
\boldsymbol{x} =  \boldsymbol{y }  \boldsymbol{A} \quad \text{(i.e., Elementwise equality)}
\end{equation}

with $ | \boldsymbol{x}|_{\infty} \le c $,  $ \boldsymbol{x} \in \mathbb{R}^{1 \times n},  \boldsymbol{y} \in \mathbb{R}^{ 1 \times m},  \boldsymbol{A} \in \mathbb{R}^{m \times n} $, and $  \boldsymbol{A} $ full row-rank.

Find a bound on the form: 
\begin{equation}\label{5}
|\boldsymbol{y} | _{\infty} \le f( c,  \boldsymbol{A})
\end{equation}

---

**My thoughts**   (feel free to ignore if you have another approach)

**1:**
Multiply both from the right  $ \boldsymbol{H} $, where $ \boldsymbol{H} $ is any generalized inverse of $ \boldsymbol{A} $ such that $    \boldsymbol{A } \boldsymbol{H} \boldsymbol{z} =  \boldsymbol{ z}\text{ for all } \boldsymbol{z} \in \mathbb{R}^{m\times 1}  $.

\begin{equation}\label{key}
\boldsymbol{x}  \boldsymbol{H} =   \boldsymbol{y}
\end{equation}

**2:** Now let $ \boldsymbol{p} \in \mathbb{R}^m$ be the $ k^{th} $ coordinate vector, that only has one nonzero element $p_k= 1 $. 
 Multiplying both sides with $  \boldsymbol{p}$ and taking the absolute norm, we get
\begin{equation}\label{1}
 |\boldsymbol{x} \boldsymbol{H}  \boldsymbol{p} |=   |{y} _{i}|
\end{equation}

**3:** Use
 \begin{equation}\label{2}
  | \boldsymbol{x} \boldsymbol{H} \boldsymbol{p}|  \le |\boldsymbol{x}|_{\infty}  |\boldsymbol{H} \boldsymbol{p}  |_{1}  \le  |\boldsymbol{x}|_{\infty}  ||\boldsymbol{H}  ||_{1} 
 \end{equation}
 Where $ ||\cdot||_{1} $ is the matrix induced norm (since $ | \boldsymbol{p}|_1 = 1 $).

\begin{equation}\label{a}
\implies {y}_i  \le||\boldsymbol{H} ||_{1} |\boldsymbol{x}|_{\infty}
\end{equation}

**4:** Since it must hold for any generalized inverse we can replace  $ \boldsymbol{H} $ with the generalized inverse $ \boldsymbol{H}_{\nu1} $ of $\boldsymbol{A}$ that minimize the matrix induced norm of $  \boldsymbol{H} $.

\begin{equation}\label{3}
{y}_i  \le|| c \boldsymbol{H}_{\nu1} ||_{1}   
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}\label{3s}
\implies  |\boldsymbol{y} | _{\infty} \ \le  c||  \boldsymbol{H}_{\nu1} ||_{1}   
\end{equation}

For simplicity, one may use the pseudo-inverse instead, i.e., $ \boldsymbol{H}=  \boldsymbol{A}^{\dagger} $ to get

\begin{equation}\label{3ss}
\implies  |\boldsymbol{y} | _{\infty} \ \le  c||  \boldsymbol{A}^{\dagger} ||_{1}   , 
\end{equation} which will yield a higher bound

---

To me it seems like the above holds. However.

-I am in general interested in other strategies that (especially if they were to yield lower bounds).

-If possible, it would be nice to get an simpler answer avoiding the use of the matrix induced norm on the inverse.

Any input is appreciated.